# How do I execute shortocde in 'Site Title' in WordPress General Settings?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to execute [year] shortcode in Site Title to show dynamic year. Created the shortcode using this:

```
add_shortcode( 'year' , 'current_year' );
function current_year() {
    $year = date("Y");
    return "$year";
}
```

Then to execute shortocde, I tried:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'do_shortcode' );
```

But none of them works.

Site Title shows up in the WordPress dashboard (in the top left corner beside WordPress icon), RSS title, in place of the logo (if none is used), and og:site_name in page source.

I'm using the RankMath plugin for SEO if that helps in any way.

Comment: We need more information to be able to help - What shortcode are you using, What exactly are you trying to do by calling it, and where are you putting the `do_shortcode` code?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've used `add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );` in functions.php. I've used the same for `wp_title` as well. None of them worked.

Comment: That's not how you use `do_shortcode`, it needs to be called in a function with the name of the shortcode you want to call. Please [edit] your question to explain what you are trying to achieve, so we can suggest an appropriate way to do it.

Comment: I've edited it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve still isn't clear - What were you hoping that do_shortcode would do? Are you trying to *change* the site title that appears in the dashboard and og:site_name? If so, it gets set in the admin, so why not change it there?

Comment: Apologies. I've updated the question again

Comment: OK, I understand what you want to do now. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it. The site title is usually always managed in the admin, and the `wp_title` and `the_title` are both for the *page/post* title, not the site title so they won't work. Sorry I can't help

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Title
 * Plugin URI: http://www.deploya.ir
 * Description: Do you want a shortcode for Page title?
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Codekit
 * Author URI: http://codekit.ir
 */
 /* title to get the post title  */
/* title to get the post title  */
function myshortcode_title( ){
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );
```

I made a plugin with this code to prevent changing function.php from updating each time